# unlimited categories/subcategories with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I'm trying to build a category/subcategory class with php & MySQL.
I am stuck with the following problem:

I want to make a selection of all categories in an ordered way like it's showed in the picture below. The table structure I've made is:

[image]

Can I build an SELECT * statement which will select these categories in  that order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: how would I go about displaying simple "categories" for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592946/mysql-how-would-i-go-about-displaying-simple-categories-for-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index your tree. There are multiple means to do so, explained in [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Comment: doing it that way will limit the subcategories number, i was looking for unlimited

Comment: @Andrei: you can make it as big as you want with either method (nested sets, materialized paths, and other hybrid approaches). The only issue is the potential performance bottleneck which creeps in at some point.